# IConfiguration in ASP.NET API, want to change GetSections's body and IConfiguration is locked. How to change GetSection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

In my appsettings.json, I have a couple of urls which I'm using them in my project.

```
  "Url1": "http://localhost:154/",
  "Url2": "https://localhost:222/",
  "Url3": "https://www.googelc.com/"
```

I'm retrieving them via _configuration.GetSection(). like this:

```
 private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
 IConfigurationSection? URL1 = _configuration.GetSection("Url1");
```

**Problem:**
If by any chance Urls which are stored in appsettings.json won't end with "/", like this:

```
 "Url1": "http://localhost:154",
```

**Project won't work properly.**

**What I want:**
I want to change _configuration.GetSection's body which any time "string key" contains "url", it checks the value ends with "/" and if it does not add "/" to the end of url.

**why I cant:**
here is IConfiguration's content:

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents a set of key/value application configuration properties.
    public interface IConfiguration
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a configuration value.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   key:
        //     The configuration key.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The configuration value.
        string this[string key]
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the immediate descendant configuration sub-sections.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The configuration sub-sections.
        IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildren();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken that can be used to observe
        //     when this configuration is reloaded.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.IChangeToken.
        IChangeToken GetReloadToken();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets a configuration sub-section with the specified key.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   key:
        //     The key of the configuration section.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     This method will never return null. If no matching sub-section is found with
        //     the specified key, an empty Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection
        //     will be returned.
        IConfigurationSection GetSection(string key);
    }
}
```

As expected IConfiguration is locked and doesn't have any implementation class.

**Main Question**

Other than checking it every time when I'm retrieving Urls in code,

- What is substitute solution?
- Is there a way for changing _Configuration.GetSection?
- Is there a way to change appsetting.json at runtime (to change urls
  dont end whit "/")?

**Temporary Solution**
I implemented a static method in a class and called in my Program.cs.
it's just being called once when app starts.

here is the method:

```
        public static void EditAppSettings()
        {
            try
            {
               var filePath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
                string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                foreach (var item in jsonObj)
                {
             
                        string value = item.Value;
                        if (value.Contains("http"))
                        {
                            if (!value.EndsWith("/"))
                                value += "/";
                            item.Value = value;
                        }
                   
                }
                string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
                File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ///do nothing
            }
        }
```

**What solution is doing>**
It opens appsettings.json and deserialize its content and accesses each item and if value has "http" and doesn't end with "/", then modifying it and at the end rewrites the appsettings.json's file!

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from doing `url.EndsWith('/') ? url : url + '/'`?

Comment: I'm retrieving other things from appsetting.json like usernames and passwords. and I dont want repeat a code every time I'm using GetSection().

Comment: Why not use the options functionality and then add a `PostConfigure` option to go through and tidy up the values in the options?

Comment: Instead of retrieving those URLs individually, I would put them in their own config subsection and use the `IOptions` pattern to inject the values into wherever they are needed. That way you can change your concrete options class to append the trailing slash when needed.

Comment: It's a big project and I'm not able to change the whole!

Comment: Why is a trailing slash a problem to begin with? That seems to be the real bug. I suspect some part of the code is using string concatenation or interpolation instead of the `Uri` class to combine URLs.

Comment: `I'm not able to change the whole` it's large projects that need to avoid haphazard settings access. Using a configuration class, eg using `IOptions` is *very* common in all projects. You're already using that pattern in many of the libraries you use, why not add it to your application as well?

Comment: A somewhat hacky way to "fix" the problem is to load all related settings and *reregister them* as a `Dictionary<string,string>`. Later additions override previous settings but that shouldn't be considered anything other than a hack

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I _did not_ read that. :)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, yes your suspicion is right, along the code Urls are being used as strings and some concatenation is involved.
Thank you for Uri class I didn't know anything about it and now I check it and figure it out any kind of url that I'm giving it as input, still works properly!